# Evadir 429 status code con Requests Python

Tags: python, python-requests

¿Hay alguna manera de evadir el código de estado 429 al mandar muchas peticiones a una página web?
Necesito recabar información de paginas para un proyecto, pero al mandar muchas peticiones me salta el error y tengo que esperar algo de tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import time

proxies = {
    "https": "http://47.90.132.228:3128",
    "http": "http://47.90.132.228:3128"
}

url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"

for i in range(10):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
        print(r.json())
    except:
        print("Sin respuesta")
    time.sleep(5)
```

El código de estado 429 se debe a que estás enviado muchas peticiones en poco tiempo. [Más información sobre el código de estado 429](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#page-3)

La solución es espaciar las peticiones. Con `time.sleep(x)` haces el programa espere `x` segundos antes de continuar con la siguiente iteración del bucle `for`.